# UpdateParameters always set to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in my updating Event on the DetailsView control. It always sets the field parentID to 0 when passing a value from a dropdownlist to the UpdateParameters collection. I know that it finds the control in the event but i can't even set a default value to "1" in my example so its to do with the UpdateParameters property can tell me what Im doing wrong and how to fix it please

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList forumGroup = DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;
    string value = forumGroup.SelectedValue.ToString();
    ObjectDataSource3.UpdateParameters["parentID"].DefaultValue = "1" // always is 0;
}


    public int UpdateForumByID(int forumID, string title, string url, string description, 
        string imageUrl, int parentID, int importance, bool moderated, bool active)
    {
        ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext("name=CMSEntities");
        ObjectSet<CMSModel.Forums> forums = context.CreateObjectSet<CMSModel.Forums>();
        // here forum is null
        CMSModel.Forums forum = forums.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ForumID == forumID);
        forum.Title = title;
        forum.Url = url;
        forum.Description = description;
        forum.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        forum.ParentID = parentID;
        forum.Importance = importance;
        forum.Moderated = moderated;
        forum.Active = active;

        int affectedRows = context.SaveChanges();

        return affectedRows;
    }
```

markup:`

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource3" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="GetForumByID" TypeName="CMS.Framework.Forums" 
            UpdateMethod="UpdateForumByID">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="forumID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="forumID" Type="Int32"  />
                <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="url" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="imageUrl" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="parentID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="parentID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="importance" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="active" Type="Boolean" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>


        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ForumID" 
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3"
            DefaultMode="Insert" 
            OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound"
            OnItemCommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand"
            OnItemUpdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ForumID" HeaderText="ForumID" 
                    SortExpression="ForumID" ReadOnly="true" InsertVisible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AddedBy" HeaderText="AddedBy" 
                    SortExpression="AddedBy" ReadOnly="true" InsertVisible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AddedDate" HeaderText="AddedDate" 
                    SortExpression="AddedDate" ReadOnly="true" InsertVisible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Url" HeaderText="Url" SortExpression="Url" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageUrl" HeaderText="ImageUrl" 
                    SortExpression="ImageUrl" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forum Group:" InsertVisible="true" SortExpression="ForumGroup">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource4" DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource4" runat="server" 
                            SelectMethod="GetDisplayForumGroups" TypeName="CMS.Framework.Forums">
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource5" DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource5" runat="server" 
                            SelectMethod="GetDisplayForumGroups" TypeName="CMS.Framework.Forums">
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Importance" HeaderText="Importance" 
                    SortExpression="Importance" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Moderated" HeaderText="Moderated" 
                    SortExpression="Moderated" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" 
                    SortExpression="Active" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedBy" HeaderText="UpdatedBy" 
                    SortExpression="UpdatedBy" ReadOnly="true" InsertVisible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedDate" HeaderText="UpdatedDate" 
                    SortExpression="UpdatedDate" ReadOnly="true" InsertVisible="true" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just bind the parameter directly to the selected value you need? [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.updateparameters.aspx) suggest something like:

```
<asp:controlparameter name="anID" controlid="DropDownList1" propertyname="SelectedValue" />
```

Comment: The dropdownlist is in the DetailsView i get this error Could not find control 'DropDownList2' in ControlParameter 'parentID'.

Comment: You have to manually pass a parameter from a dropdownlist in detailsview don't you on the updating event. the updating event is always setting a Default parentID parameter to 0. i've updated my code to show you what i mean

Comment: My mistake I didn't add the Event in the detailsview. I need to pay attention focus